# Setting Global Variable from Jupyter Comm

Tags: javascript, python, d3.js, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to access data from a python cell in javascript in a Jupyter notebook. I am using Jupyter's Comm feature. The following HTML cell is setup to provide d3js as well as a `<div>` that d3 can select.

```
%%HTML
<div class="anchor"></div>
<script>
    requirejs.config({
        paths: {
            d3: 'https://d3js.org/d3.v5'
        }
    });

    require(['d3'], function(d3) {
        window.d3 = d3;
    });
</script>
```

Next I run a python cell to send the comm data.

```
def target_func(comm, msg):
    comm.send({'abc': 123})

get_ipython().kernel.comm_manager.register_target('data', target_func)
```

Finally, I run a javascript cell to display the data from the python cell above. I am logging to the console as well to make sure the data is really there (and it is).

```
%%javascript
var comm = Jupyter.notebook.kernel.comm_manager.new_comm('data');
var temp
comm.on_msg(function(msg) {
    console.log(msg.content.data);
    temp = msg
});

d3.select(".anchor").append("span").text(temp);
```

Problem: I am unable to get the data from the comm message outside of the scope of the function. In the example above, when d3 appends the span with text, that variable, `temp` is undefined.

How do I get the data from the comm message out of that function's scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you call `d3.select(".anchor").append("span").text(temp);` *inside* the `on_msg` callback?

e.g.:

```
%%javascript
var comm = Jupyter.notebook.kernel.comm_manager.new_comm('data');
var temp
comm.on_msg(function(msg) {
    console.log(msg.content.data);
    temp = msg
    d3.select(".anchor").append("span").text(temp);
});
```

I think your mistake is that you are calling the d3 stuff right after *defining* and *attaching* the `on_msg` callback. The act of defining and attaching that callback *does not* make it run immediately. It only runs whenever a message is received from the kernel *and* the JavaScript runtime happens to be free to run it.

So what was really happening was that you defined and attached the callback, then executed the d3 stuff, and then the JavaScript engine finished evaluating the block. And only after it has finished evaluating the block does the engine become free to accept the message from the kernel and fire the callback, by which time it was too late because you had already called the d3 stuff.